# Fix Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {_40, _65, _55, _72})

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have an array of ids. I want to run a map function that loops through the array of ids. Each time a new id element is looped to, I want to use that id to trigger a function that returns an object. I then want to use that object's values to return content. Here's my code:

```
...
getConversationInfo = async (conversation_id, listing_type, listing_id, user_id, sender_id, respondent_id) => {
    let conversation = await axios.get(`${propState.host}/api/conversation/${listing_type}/${listing_id}/${user_id}/${sender_id}/${respondent_id}`);
    conversation = conversation.data;
    console.log("conversation: ", conversation);

    let listing = await conversation.listing;
    let person_you_are_messaging = await conversation.person_you_are_messaging;

    let listing_name;

    if(listing.business_name) {
      listing_name = await listing.business_name;
    } else {
      listing_name = await listing.short_description;
    }

    let conversationObj = 
    {
      listing_name: listing_name,
      person_you_are_messaging: person_you_are_messaging.first_name + " " + person_you_are_messaging.last_name
    };

    console.log("conversationObj: ", conversationObj);
    return conversationObj;
  }

...

render() {
    const { user_id, conversations, showNoConversationsMessage, showShowMoreButton, loading } = this.state;

    return (
      ...
          <ScrollView>
              <View style={styles.body}>
                  {conversations.map(async (e, i) => {
                    let conversationObj = await this.getConversationInfo(e.conversation_id, e.listing_type, e.listing_id, user_id, e.sender_id, e.respondent_id);
                    console.log("in map conversation: ", conversationObj, conversationObj.listing_name, conversationObj.person_you_are_messaging);
                    
                    return (
                      <TouchableOpacity 
                        key={i}
                        style={styles.conversation}
                        onPress={() => {
                          this.props.updateSingleState("conversation_id", e.conversation_id);
                          this.props.updateState("Conversation");
                        }}
                      >
                        <Text style={styles.text}>Listing Name: {conversationObj.listing_name}</Text>
                        <Text style={styles.text}>Sender or Respondent Name: {conversationObj.person_you_are_messaging}</Text>
                      </TouchableOpacity>
                    )
                  } 
               )}
             </View>
           </ScrollView>
          
...
```

My console.log in the map function returns the value I want. But I always get this error:

"Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {_40, _65, _55, _72}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead."

How do I make the error message go away?

Comment: can you share the console.log result

Answer (score 0):

In `{conversations.map(async (e, i) => {` conversations is not an Array.

Make sure that you are returning 'conversationObj' as an Array.

Use 'try catch' method and make some validation to the conversationObj before returning it

Comment: I tried all of those things already and it didn't work. I ended up running all the same functionality in the componentDidMount method to update state, then used that info in the map function.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of running the getConversationInfo function inside of the map function, I ran it inside of the componentDidMount and combined that information with the this.state.conversations information and it all worked.

I think the biggest lesson is to never update the information that is inside of the render method within a map function. It's best to update the state in componentDidMount first, then use that information for any map functions you use.